# two if in a JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop, sticky

I have a question, I will make a sticky content. It will works with CSS and ad classes...

my Problem is I don't know how to ask 2 if's...

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){

    var fix_work_content = $(".portfolio_work").offset().top -20;
    var leave_work_content = $(".mainfooter").offset().top -50;


    if($(document).scrollTop()>fix_work_content){
        $(".work_content").addClass("fix_work_content").removeClass("leave_work_content");
    } 
    /*
    if($(document).scrollTop()>leave_work_content){
        $(".work_content").addClass("leave_work_content").removeClass("fix_work_content");
    } 
    */
    else{
        $(".work_content").removeClass("fix_work_content, fix_work_content");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to test a second condition before going to the else block? If so, this is what you want:

```
if (condition){

} else if (another_condition){

} else {

}
```

Using your code:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){

    var fix_work_content = $(".portfolio_work").offset().top -20;
    var leave_work_content = $(".mainfooter").offset().top -50;   

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > fix_work_content){
        $(".work_content").addClass("fix_work_content").removeClass("leave_work_content");
    } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > leave_work_content){
        $(".work_content").addClass("leave_work_content").removeClass("fix_work_content");
    } else {
        $(".work_content").removeClass("fix_work_content, fix_work_content");
    }
});
```

Whether the code does what you want I can't say.